# MaterialShowsaseView skip option

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am using Material showcase library in my android app:-
https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView

And using sequential showcase. But I am not able to find a way to skip the showcase item on single click.
Is there anyone who has done this using this or some other better library?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks